# Shortest way to "or" a list of booleans in javascript

Tags: javascript, boolean-expression

I have a list of booleans. I want to apply `||` ("or") on each of them, and get the result. (So, a new boolean.)

The list has no fixed length, so I can't simply write the code as `value = l[0] || ... l[length-1]`. (It would also be ugly for long lists.)

My approach:

```
let index = 0;
let value = true;
while(index < list.length && value == value || list[index]) {
    index += 1;
}
```

I guess that this is possible as one statement. How?

Comment: Does the code work as currently written?

Comment: Are you aware of `Array.prototype.some`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: Applying an 'or' to each of the indexes of your list of booleans is the same as checking if any of them are actually true, so you could literally just see if the list has the value 'true' in it, using ```Array.includes(true)```

Comment: "or" is cheap, when used on a large bunch. (Very fast.) How expensive are those functions?

Comment: @Asqiir: Not very. They’re just function calls plus very similar loops, and JavaScript engines are decent at function calls. If you profile and this turns out to be a bottleneck, you can compare them. (I expect `includes` to be the fastest and about as good as a loop.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use [`.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), which checks if an Array includes a value, and returns `true` / `false`

```js
const list = [true, true, true, true, false];

// Checks if list contains the Boolean True
const value = list.includes(true);

console.log(value);
```

Comment: I think the intended result is `const value = list.includes(true);`.

Comment: What is `index`? It's certainly not any index of the array. It can also only be either `0` or `1`. So, it's more of a boolean.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use `.some`:

```
const value = list.some(Boolean);
```

```js
const list = [false, false, false, true, false];
const value = list.some(Boolean);
console.log(value);
```

```js
const list = [false, false, false, false, false];
const value = list.some(Boolean);
console.log(value);
```

Comment: `.some` works, but `.includes` in the other answer really is a more appropriate choice.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, this is *exactly* what [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.reduce) is for:

```js
list.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue || currentValue)
```

[`reduce` (or `fold` as it is called in some other languages)](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29) is a *general method of iteration* which means that *anything you can do with a loop*, you can also do with `reduce`. What `reduce` does, is use a binary operation to "fold" all elements of a collection into a new value. In this case, it is a rather simple operation, and the result type is the same type as the elements, but that doesn't have to be the case: the result type can be different than the element type, and the result type can be arbitrarily complex (it can even be again a collection).

You can think of `reduce` as replacing the comma in an array with a binary operator. In other words, if you have

```js
const arr = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g];
```

then

```js
arr.reduce((accumulator, element) => accumulator + element)
```

will compute

```js
a + b + c + d + e + f + g
```

However, because `reduce` is a *general* method, it doesn't convey much meaning. There are more specialized methods that cannot do "everything", but using those methods tells the reader more about what is going on in your code. So, for example, you *can* use `reduce` to transform each element, but you *should* rather use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.map) for that.

Note that your specific example has some specific properties: since `OR`-ing a bunch of values together is only `false` if every single value is `false`, or in other words, is `true` if at least one value is `true`, all we need to check is if there is *some* element that is `true`.

And there is a specific method for checking whether some element has a specific property: [`Array.prototype.some`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.some):

```js
list.some(el => el)
```

In this case, the property is actually just the *identity function*. Alternatively, you can use the [`Boolean` constructor](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-boolean-constructor), which acts as the identity function for booleans:

```js
list.some(Boolean)
```

you can also use [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.includes) to check if the list includes at least one `true` value:

```js
list.includes(true)
```

Comment: Incredibly verbose and inefficient (not short-circuiting) compared to `some` or `includes`, so not *exactly*…

Comment: This is definitely not "exactly" what `reduce` is for. The primary case for `reduce` is combining values, you should use `includes` for checking if a value exists or `some` to check for the existence of truthiness.

Comment: @Ry- "logical or" returns the value of the variable, which is not necessarily a boolean. `some` does not work to retrieve that value.

Comment: @ASDFGerte: ”I have a list of booleans.” ”I want to … get the result. (So, a new boolean.)” (later edit FWIW: short-circuiting `||` for non-booleans is `list.find(Boolean)`.)

Comment: @JohnMontgomery applying the same operation to all is *exactly* what is happening here. The reduce operation could have just been `(a, b) => a + b` but here it's `(a, b) => a || b` it's fundamentally the same kind of operation - it's just algebra but with booleans instead of numbers.

Comment: @VLAZ OP wants to check if the list has at least one true value. `includes` or `some` is much better for that.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery which doesn't make a `reduce` operation *wrong*.

Comment: @VLAZ No, but as mentioned it's verbose and inefficient and there's no reason to prefer it here.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: You could wait till the answer’s fully finished to post it, or just edit documentation links into the answers that are already better instead of merging them into yours.

Comment: @JörgWMittag People have no way of knowing that you're still working on your answer, especially with how many times I see someone post an incomplete answer just to get it in first. If you're worried about losing your work, you can write it in a separate text editor. Otherwise, expect people to respond to the current version of what you've posted.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Now that's just ignoring a trivial XY problem. ORing a list of booleans is logically equivalent to checking if it has at least one true value, and nothing in the question says they can't use a more efficient method.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic use case for `reduce`:

```
value = list.reduce((a, b) => a || b, false);
```

(Note the starting accumulator value should be `false` - using `true` as you are, the result will *always* be `true`!)

Comment: some or includes makes more sense since reduce visits every index

Comment: Agreed - `reduce` popped into my head instantly (what can I say, I'm a functional programmer at heart :) ), but with this specific problem I agree that those are probably better solutions. (Although I'm sceptical whether you'd ever be able to actually observe the theoretical performance difference in practice.)